# Use of function application operator in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, operators, function-calls

What does the following expression means in haskell?

```
($ 3)
```

ghci shows the following type

```
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b.
```

Answer (score 8):

`($ 3)` is a section, and is equivalent to `\f -> f 3`, which takes a function argument and applies it to 3.

If we considered `3` to be an integer, we would have that the type of `f` is `Int -> b` (for any `b`), so the type of `($ 3)` would be `(Int -> b) -> b`.

Things in Haskell are a bit more complex, since `3` can be of any numeric type, so we don't really need `f :: Int -> b`, it's enough if `f :: a -> b` where `a` is a numeric type.

Hence we get `($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b`.

Answer (score 6):

`(@ x)` for any operator `@` is equivalent to `\a -> a @ x`; so `($ 3)` is equivalent to `\f -> f $ 3`, i.e. a function that applies any function you pass it to `3`. This syntax is called "sections".

```
> let f = ($ 3)
> f show
"3"
> f square
9
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it is

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
3 :: Num a => a
```

and when you "insert 3" in the `($)` it will become

```
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b.
```

due to that you no longer need to supply the a, but the function you need to supply is now restricted to num, since the 3 can be any numeric type.

This is at least how I look at functions in Haskell, like substitution in algebra.